# Can an SQL alias be a function? (PL/SQL)

Tags: plsql

I'm making a daily report that will produce a value for the next 7 days as such:

```
select
a.itemnumber
,sum(case when a.activitydate = trunc(sysdate) then a.qtyordered else 0 end) as Today
,sum(case when a.activitydate = trunc(sysdate) + 1 then a.qtyordered else 0 end) as Tomorrow
,sum(case when a.activitydate = trunc(sysdate) + 2 then a.qtyordered else 0 end) as Day3
,sum(case when a.activitydate = trunc(sysdate) + 3 then a.qtyordered else 0 end) as Day4
,sum(case when a.activitydate = trunc(sysdate) + 4 then a.qtyordered else 0 end) as Day5
,sum(case when a.activitydate = trunc(sysdate) + 5 then a.qtyordered else 0 end) as Day6
,sum(case when a.activitydate = trunc(sysdate) + 6 then a.qtyordered else 0 end) as Day7
,a.balanceonhand BOH

from
mytable a

where
a.itemnumber between 14000 and 15000
```

These aliases are more ambiguous than I would like, and especially if the user compares reports from one day to another, these mean nothing.  Using PL/SQL Developer, can I make an alias that will produce a variable date?  I tried the following code:

```
select
a.itemnumber
,sum(case when a.activitydate = trunc(sysdate) then a.qtyordered else 0 end) as sysdate
,sum(case when a.activitydate = trunc(sysdate) + 1 then a.qtyordered else 0 end) as sysdate + 1
,sum(case when a.activitydate = trunc(sysdate) + 2 then a.qtyordered else 0 end) as sysdate + 2
,sum(case when a.activitydate = trunc(sysdate) + 3 then a.qtyordered else 0 end) as sysdate + 3
,sum(case when a.activitydate = trunc(sysdate) + 4 then a.qtyordered else 0 end) as sysdate + 4
,sum(case when a.activitydate = trunc(sysdate) + 5 then a.qtyordered else 0 end) as sysdate + 5
,sum(case when a.activitydate = trunc(sysdate) + 6 then a.qtyordered else 0 end) as sysdate + 6
,a.balanceonhand BOH

from
mytable a

where
a.itemnumber between 14000 and 15000

group by
a.itemnumber
,a.balanceonhand
```

But it says the FROM keyword not found where expected.  Is this possible?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible.  You'd have to use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier if you use a row generator to get your seven dates (or indeed any number of dates).  This will provide the data in row based format.

From there I suggest PIVOT is a good way to reformat the output into columns rather than rows. I've provided an 'offset' column in the dategen query so that this can be added to the startdate which, in this case, is a sqlplus variable but I'd suggest using a bind variable in the production query.  I'd strongly recommend against using SYSDATE as this makes things very hard to test.  It's easier when you can change the dates covered by the report to suit available test data.

```
  1  WITH
  2  dategen
  3  as
  4  (
  5  SELECT TO_DATE('&startdate','DD-MON-YYYY')+LEVEL mydate, LEVEL myoffset
  6  FROM dual
  7  CONNECT BY LEVEL <=7)
  8  SELECT itemnumber,balanceonhand, activitydate, today, tomorrow, day3, day4, day5, day6, day7
  9  FROM (
 10  SELECT *
 11  FROM mytable t
 12  JOIN dategen d ON (d.mydate = t.activitydate)
 13  PIVOT (
 14    SUM(qtyordered)
 15    FOR myoffset IN (0 as today,1 as tomorrow,2 day3,3 as day4, 4 as day5, 5 as day6, 6 as day7)
 16* ))
SQL> /
Enter value for startdate: 01-JAN-2015
old   5: SELECT TO_DATE('&startdate','DD-MON-YYYY')+(level-1) mydate, LEVEL myoffset
new   5: SELECT TO_DATE('01-JAN-2015','DD-MON-YYYY')+(level-1) mydate, LEVEL myoffset
```

ITEMNUMBER BALANCEONHAND ACTIVITYDATE        TODAY   TOMORROW   DAY3       DAY4       DAY5   DAY6       DAY7

---

```
   120       100 02-JAN-15                 10
   140       100 04-JAN-15                           10
   100       100 02-JAN-15                 10
```

3 rows selected.

```
SQL> select * from mytable;

ITEMNUMBER BALANCEONHAND ACTIVITYDATE       QTYORDERED
---------- ------------- ------------------ ----------
       100       100 02-JAN-15          10
       120       100 02-JAN-15          10
       140       100 04-JAN-15          10

3 rows selected.
```